# Should we create a tag for "Mapsui"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Can someone please create a tag for [Mapsui](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui)?

It's a really useful and fairly new control for mapping (as a fork from SharpMap). My recent Mapsui related question [question available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260870/change-the-panning-button-in-mapsui-control)  could use this tag.

As Mapsui is a fork of Sharpmap, Mapsui specific issues need to be differentiated. Also, because Mapsui is a new control, the tag will help group and build knowledge of the control while the documentation is in its infancy.

**Suggested tag name**

mapsui

**Excerpt**

Mapsui (pronounced map-su-wii) is a C# map component for application that supports WPF, UWP, Android, iOS and started as a fork of SharpMap.

**Wiki**

Mapsui (pronounced map-su-wii) is a C# map component for application. Mapsui is a GIS tool capable of loading vector and Bitmap data using built in styles or custom styles.

Mapsui supported WPF, UWP, Android and iOS platforms. The Mapsui core assembly is PCL Profile 111 for v1 and .NET Standard 1.3 for v2. Mapsui is designed to be fast and responsive and leverages to capabilities of SharpMap as it started as a fork of SharpMap.

Mapsui is distributed on GitHub and NuGet under an LGPL license.

Comment: Please read and follow [the guidelines for tag creation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Just read. What do you mean by follow? Is there something specific you think I am not following? I note that in the link you sent states that Tags should be requested in your question where it is required, however, when you try to add a tag without the required reputation is states that you should request it as a question here so I think I am in the right.

Comment: @Richard You've actually got quite a few of the points already done, such as adding the comment to your question that it should be added, and naming in this request what question it should be added to, which is good. A couple of things you are missing are: 1)Provide an initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag, 2)Explain how the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions, and 3)Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow (For this last one you're half way there already with explaining what the tag is, just further explain why the tag is "really useful")

Comment: Indeed, it also states that you should address 5 topics in your request. You've already addressed the first point, and somewhat addressed the second and third point. The main thing still missing is an initial tag excerpt and wiki. Can you write up something?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Hopefully a bit closer to what you need now. If it's still lacking then please let me know and I'll have another think. Thanks.

Comment: The excerpt (and to some extent the wiki) need to provide guidance *when* the tag should be applied to questions. The excerpt and wiki **should not** be like an ad campaign or other promotional chit-chat. Users that come here to ask a question (or answer them) already know what it is.

Comment: @rene to be fair, what percentage of the tag excerpt follow that guidance :) I think we can start with the excerpt/wiki provided by OP, if someone wants to improve then they can suggest an edit.

Comment: @Stijn recently some have told me that instead of doing burninations I should be more strict on tag creation. I guess I just started doing that ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created the [mapsui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapsui) tag.

Out of the 9 or so questions that [contains "mapsui"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=mapsui%20is%3Aq&mixed=0), I've [tagged three of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bmapsui%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0) and [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=mapsui%20is%3Aq%20closed%3Ayes&mixed=0) four library recommendations.