# Questions about WCAG 2.1: use wcag2.0 tag or create a new one?

Tags: discussion, tags

SO currently has a [wcag2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2.0) tag and a [wcag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag) tag. WCAG 1.0 was published in the late 1990s and is outdated. [WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) was published in December 2008; since the publication of [WCAG 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) in June 2018, we are now in a [transition period](https://www.w3.org/blog/2018/06/wcag21-rec/) where both WCAG 2.0 and WCAG 2.1 are valid W3C recommendations.

WCAG 2.1 introduced a number of new requirements (new "success criteria") but did not change the existing ones; each website that conforms to WCAG 2.1 also conforms to WCAG 2.0 (at the same conformance level), but websites that conform to WCAG 2.0 don't automatically conform to WCAG 2.1 (due to the new requirements).

Some questions about WCAG conformance don't specify which WCAG version they have in mind, i.e. WCAG 2.0 or WCAG 2.1, although this can make a difference. Some of these questions use the tag [wcag2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2.0) since there is no tag for [wcag2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2.1) yet. I propose that we **create a [wcag2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2.1) tag**. The alternatives appear less attractive:

- a tag such as [wcag2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2) or [wcag2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2.x) would be ambiguous;
- the tag [wcag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag) is even more ambiguous.

WCAG versions are meant to be stable for a long time, so it is unlikely that we will soon need a tag such as [wcag2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcag2.2). The W3C has started working on [WCAG Silver](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/task-forces/silver/wiki/Main_Page), but this is better thought of as "WCAG 3.0" (the W3C has been avoiding this designation, though) than "WCAG 2.2".

Comment: Sounds like a good request. See [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/7296893): ask the question first under the best available tag (probably only wcag), then edit this question to include a link. Then, we can retag the question to include the new tag.

Comment: Is there anyone that when you tell them wcag would think about the '90 specification? I didn't even knew wcag had different versions. BTW, according to the 2.1 spec "This additive approach helps to make it clear that sites which conform to WCAG 2.1 also conform to WCAG 2.0, thereby meeting conformance obligations that are specific to WCAG 2.0." So, having separated tags doesn't help to be more conformant.

Comment: @Braiam We might have a number of older questions about WCAG 1.0, especially because of legislation that was still based on it in the first years after WCAG 2.0 was published. We will have a similar situation with the transition to WCAG 2.1, especially after the European Accessibility Act has been voted (presumably this year).

Comment: We can't create a tag for you if you don't show us at least 1 question where it would be appropriate.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That should be an answer.

Comment: Are there any questions tagged with [tag:wcag2.0] that wouldn't be better tagged with [tag:wcag]?

Comment: @TylerH I was thinking Christophe actually had a question, then the answer could be: tag created on question ... with excerpt .... I'd rather leave this unanswered till the tag actually has been created (or it has been decided we shouldn't create the tag)

Comment: @zzzzBov I am not in favour of making [tag:wcag] even more ambiguous then it currently is. WCAG 1.0, WCAG 2.0, WCAG 2.1: that's already three different WCAG versions.

Comment: @Cœur [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54062501/6002174) *might* qualify, but like many other recent WCAG-related questions, it is answered by referring to requirements that did not change between WCAG 2.0 and WCAG 2.1.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe, most questions aren't about a _specific_ version though. Most questions should probably be tagged with `wcag` and any version-specific questions can then include the tag for the specific version. To that point, `html` is ambiguous, but the vast majority of questions asking about HTML should be tagged with that tag because we understand that modern users aren't asking about html1.

Comment: @zzzzBov In my opinion, the comparison with HTML doesn't work very well, because WCAG requirements have become part of legislation. From a legal point of view, conforming to WCAG 1.0 is useless, unless you somehow also conform to WCAG 2.0 or (soon) WCAG 2.1. By contrast, HTML 4 elements mostly continue working in present-day browsers.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe, I don't see how legislation is relevant to the questions on Stack Overflow. I asked for data before and I'm going to ask you for data again. How many questions tagged with _any_ of the WCAG tags relate to legal conformance to WCAG?

Comment: @zzzzBov I am not claiming that legislation is relevant here, but that developers of websites that need to comply to legislation that requires WCAG 2.0 conformance will rarely be interested in questions about WCAG 1.0. There will also be questions about WCAG 2.1 that can't be answered by referring to WCAG 2.0.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe, how many `wcag` tickets are explicitly about `wcag 1.0`? You keep making these claims but I don't see any data to back up the concerns. If someone's looking for wcag information, why do you think they'd have a hard time finding relevant information? Do you have data that indicates that there are so many `wcag1.0`-only questions tagged with `wcag` that it's nigh on impossible to find relevant `wcag2.0` questions and answers?