# Create [billiard]

Tags: support, tags

For this question here, [Python Multiprocessing: billiard vs multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54858326/9059420), I tried to replace the wrong tag [billiards], which is about the game, with [billiard], the [Python 2.7 multiprocessing-fork](https://pypi.org/project/billiard/). This would have created the billiard-tag, but I get this message:

[image]

Comment: [tag:python-billiard]? Please have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: @BDL Thx, python-billiard is also fine I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We should not have any tags called [billiard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/billiard) or [billiards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/billiards). They are ambiguous and not necessarily about programming.

What you could do is to create a tag [python-billiard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-billiard), which is sufficiently narrow and has a clear scope. Since I don't know the topic, I can't tell if there's a need for such a tag or if [python-multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-multiprocessing) is sufficient to cover it.

Comment: Would go with `python-billiard` then, `python-multiprocessing` would be ambiguous here.

Comment: @Darkonaut My remark about that is: will this Billiard thing have at least some traffic and distinguish itself enough to merit a tag of its own? As in, will it be used. I have no idea if the tag makes sense myself, the Python community has to make that call.

Comment: In the link @BDL provided it's stated that: "Uncommon topics are perfectly valid for a tag, as long as they're still clearly defined. "- so high traffic is not a prerequisite. Traffic will be low, but it distinguishes clearly since it's an alternative to Python's multiprocessing module in the standard library. So to prefix it with "python" could be even missleading IMO.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why my question provoked so much downvotes. There is no clear line when to prefix with a language tag. There are so many tags out there which don't have it (e.g. [dill]), although they deal exclusively with python and the link @BDL provided also doesn't lose a word about how to deal with it. Anyway, I created `python-billiard` and provided a wiki excerpt which explains what billiard is about, so people don't need to google it.