# Rename tag [azure-machine-learning] to [azure-machine-learning-studio] and add [azure-machine-learning-service]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Last year Microsoft released a new cloud service called Azure Machine Learning Service.

[To quote Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/overview-what-is-azure-ml#how-is-azure-machine-learning-service-different-from-machine-learning-studio):

> Azure Machine Learning service is a cloud service that you use to train, deploy, automate, and manage machine learning models, all at the broad scale that the cloud provides.

Previously Microsoft already released a product called Azure Machine Learning Studio which is entirely separate from the new service

> Azure Machine Learning Studio is a collaborative, drag-and-drop visual workspace where you can build, test, and deploy machine learning solutions without needing to write code. It uses prebuilt and preconfigured machine learning algorithms and data-handling modules.
>
> Models created in Azure Machine Learning Studio can't be deployed or managed by Azure Machine Learning service.

On Stack Overflow the tag [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) was used for questions relating to AML Studio, however, now with the new service I'd like to request to rename [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) to [azure-machine-learning-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-studio) and add a new tag [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service) to distinguish the two.

Comment: Do you have any existing questions that could use the new tag? Tags can only be created by adding them to a new or existing question, see [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: I actually wanted to ask a question relating to AML Service when I noticed no tag existed for it yet. But to answer your question, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509207/data-sources-in-azure-machine-learning-services-deployed-web-service-usage-outs) from today relates to it. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353889/azure-container-instances-deployment-failed) from march

Comment: I've added the new tag. Apparently we also have [tag:azure-machine-learning-workbench].

Comment: Thanks. Workbench is a deprecated part of AML Service: [The Azure Machine Learning Workbench application and some other early features were deprecated and replaced in the September 2018 release to make way for an improved architecture.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/overview-what-happened-to-workbench)