# Remove [azure-machine-learning] as the tag synonym for [azure-machine-learning-studio]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

I would like to see the tag [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) to no longer be a synonym of [azure-machine-learning-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-studio). [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) is a much bigger product now, so the synonym is incorrect.

Here are some examples of posts that are not related to studio:

- [Share notebooks across Azure Machine learning service notebook VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558892/share-notebooks-across-azure-machine-learning-service-notebook-vm)
- [Image Classification in Azure Machine Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450223/image-classification-in-azure-machine-learning)
- [Which Azure storage technology for weather forecast data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187227/which-azure-storage-technology-for-weather-forecast-data)
  there are many, many more....

How can we remove the tag synonym?

Comment: Check this post which had asked for the creation of synonym: [Rename tag \[azure-machine-learning\] to \[azure-machine-learning-studio\] and add \[azure-machine-learning-service\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382435/rename-tag-azure-machine-learning-to-azure-machine-learning-studio-and-add)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the original ask -- it made sense to create the synonym at the time, but now that the new tag has been established, can we remove the synonym so people can ask questions for [azure-machine-learning], too?

Comment: Sure, we can. Once we get enough community support here, we can remove it.

Comment: Ok -- how should people express their support?

Comment: By voting on the question. Once it receives some upvotes, then we can remove the synonym.

Answer (score 1):

The tag was renamed and synonymized in April this year, after a request went out asking for the same: [Rename tag [azure-machine-learning] to [azure-machine-learning-studio] and add [azure-machine-learning-service]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382435/4099593). The reason cited there was because of the use of the tag [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) to ask questions about AML Studio, and therefore the rename was apt. The resolution at the end of that meta left us with two new tags:

- [azure-machine-learning-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-studio): for AML Studio questions
- [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service): for the cloud based machine learning service.

Now if we break the synonym and recreate [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) as a separate tag, the problem that I can foresee is that questions about AML Studio being asked with the [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) tag. We need to have tags that are more clear in their names.

That said, I have removed the synonym, based on the community vote here, and popularity of this request. Let me know if you can think of a better name for either of the two tags which can help reduce the number of incorrectly tagged posts.