# What is win32gui? Because there's the confusing [win32gui] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

What is win32gui? Because there's the confusing [win32gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32gui) tag...

It [calls itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32gui) "a C++ generic library for Win32 GUI programming."

But there's [a Python Library](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/) with the exact same name.

Comment: Apparently the C++ guys won the race to create a tag here. If you want one for the Python library, petition someone with > 1500 rep to create a `python-win32gui` tag... You might try a tag-specific [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)... See [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey The ratio of [c++] to [python] among those questions is only 2:1, and the oldest Python question is older than its C++ counterpart. Would there be a case for splitting the tag into [c++-win32gui] and [python-win32gui]? Or should the tag wiki be changed so that both meanings are covered?

Comment: If the differentiation is between C++ and Python libraries, I think the tag names would be better with the language as the second component, e.g. `win32gui-c++` and `win32gui-python`.

Comment: @BobJarvis yet all other such tags put the language first. [tag:python-dateutil], [tag:python-requests], [tag:jruby-win32ole], etc.

Comment: Python libraries suffer from naming problems, there are so many to choose from and their authors pick the most obviously appropriate name.  It is not a problem in practice, anybody that asks a question about the library knows to *also* prefix [python].  No, nobody in [c++] land will be confused about it.  Not in the least because [win32gui] is a contextual tag in that language.

Comment: The real problem seems to be that the non-Python questions are actually about the Win32 GUI, as opposed to win32gui. Which isn't surprising, seeing as the C++ win32gui was last updated 15 years ago.

Comment: I like [Han's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385699/what-is-win32gui-because-theres-the-confusing-win32gui-tag#comment701075_385699). Since both the C++ library and Python module use the Win32/COM API, why not make the tag description generic for both languages and edit it to contain something similar to [tag:tensorflow]'s: "_PLEASE ADD THE LANGUAGE TAG YOU ARE DEVELOPING IN. TENSORFLOW SUPPORTS MORE THAN ONE LANGUAGE_"

Comment: @HereticMonkey The tag wasn't created for that C++ library, though. The wiki was created on 2012-08-06. Before that date, there already were [93 questions under it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwin32gui%5D+created%3A..2012-08-06+is%3Aq), questions that are only connected by somehow having to do with Win32gui GUIs in the general sense.

Comment: @duplode It doesn't really matter that much, does it? Whether I say "the C++ guys won the race to create the tag" or "the C++ guys won the race to edit the wiki"? Seems like hairs are getting split, and I for one can't afford to lose any more hair. I happen to agree with ivan's answer: let's just get rid of both.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My gripe is that it shouldn't be possible to claim a tag by arbitrarily slapping on it a wiki that isn't representative of the questions under it. In any case, we do agree on Ivan's answer, so that discussion is indeed better left for another day.

Answer (score 34):

The PyPI entry is a spin-off from Pywin32 (and links to that project as reference) and is [unmaintained to boot](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/#history) (last release in 2017), so it having no tag is a non-issue.

The same [can be said for the C++ library](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/#history) (last release in 2005).

Looking at the tagged questions, the tag is rather being used for questions about GUI programming in Windows.

My opinion is that used like that, this is a meta tag because without a specific technology in mind ([winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi), [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms), [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) etc), such a question is going to be too broad -- so the tag doesn't add any information that a technology tag or [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) wouldn't.

As such, **I propose to burninate this tag as ambiguous** and **do not disambiguate it at the same time because there's no need to.**

Comment: i would support this I seen win32gui and thought it was about the Win32 Library for GUI application (C++, C#, VB.NET) all use the old Windows Messaging system for handling events to the UI, unlike the WPF API.