# Need to create a tag for KAS-ECC

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-process

Can someone please help me create a tag for KAS-ECC algorithms?
I don't see any tags on Stack Overflow for KAS and I do not have the privileges to create it.

Comment: Is the lack of this tag causing issues...do other [tag:algorithm] tags not do the job? What would the tag-wiki say?

Comment: No this is separate category. ECC is a specific one which is why I looked for KAS (Key agreement scheme). And didn't find that either.

Comment: I understand it's a separate category but I question the **need** for the tag. Is the fact that it doesn't exist really cause any issues?

Comment: The only reason I ask is because when I'm asking a question, I can tag OpenSSL (which is the library I'm using). But if I say OpenSSL, there might be lot of people willing to help without knowing what category of algs I'm talking about. People who are trying to help me might just assume it's one of the straight forward algs under OpenSSL. If that does not justify creating a new tag, I can always add it in the description of the question.

Comment: @amy123 I recommend reading [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/479156). (Especially the "_Topics to be addressed in the meta post are_..." part and try to [edit] your post accordingly.)

Comment: Welcome to Meta, by the way. Votes here are different than at the main site: people will vote up if it's useful, well researched, and they agree with it, or downvote if you didn't do your research or they don't like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that we'd need these tags.

I can't see that these sites have these tags either:

[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

[When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/3956566):

> If you do not have enough reputation to create the tag, then add a comment on your question. Say that you wanted to add the tag to the question, but do not have enough reputation. Please consider including a reason why you think this tag is appropriate. If someone with enough reputation agrees with you, they will be able to create the tag. Please delete your comment once this has happened.