# Create tag [nginx-plus]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Can someone create the [nginx-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx-plus) tag?

For those unfamiliar with [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/), nginx is a web server that's used as a reverse proxy, load balancer, and many other uses.

Although nginx is free software, there's also a proprietary version of nginx called *nginx plus* which is [released as a commercial product](https://www.nginx.com/blog/whats-difference-nginx-foss-nginx-plus/).

The key difference between both projects is that nginx-plus includes additional features that are not available to users of nginx's OSS releases.

Currently, Stack Overflow includes a bunch of questions regarding nginx-plus and its additional features. This poses a problem as users who use Stack Overflow to take their first steps with nginx and thus answer their questions regarding how the software can be used will be presented with search results regarding features that are only available in paid versions of the product.

Adding a nginx-plus tag would fix this problem. Users who are only interested in the OSS version of nginx can simply exclude the tag from their queries to increase the quality of their search results.

Conversely, users who are interested in features that are only present in the commercial version of nginx can simply add the nginx-plus tag to omit any references to the OSS release.

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: "Currently Stack Overflow includes a bunch of questions regarding nginx-plus and its additional features" so, I went through these questions, and found that these has higher answer rate than plain nginx and that the entire site. Is there really a problem from the asker perspective if they questions are getting answers?

Comment: @Braiam from the asker perspective there might not be a problem as nginx-plus is a strict subset of nginx.  However, there is a significant problem for those who search for specific nginx topics as questions (and answers) specific to nginx-plus just add noise to the search results.  For example, there are auth features that are only shipped in nginx-plus, and if a nginx user searches for auth-related topics then he will be flooded by unrelated search results that he can't simply filter out.

Comment: I can't buy that argument. Nginx plus is nginx + proprietary extensions. Anything you can do with nginx you can do it with nginx plus. They even say so in their [difference pages](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/#compare-versions). BTW, people looking to answer nginx plus questions may just want to answer any nginx question instead, since they are more common than the superset.

Comment: @RAM if you can point out the questions that don't have the nginx-plus tag but should, we'll be happy to take a look at them and add the tag if necessary. As someone who uses nginx, I do get irritated when I see a resource about nginx-plus that basically requires me to write the plugin myself for NGINX.