# I propose to add "Stripe" tag in stackoverflow for the general questions related to Stripe Implementation

Tags: support, status-declined, tags

When I say Stripe I mean: https://stripe.com/gb

This can be integrated into an app in various ways, like:

- Stripe Connect
- Payment Integration
- etc...

I propose to add a tag "Stripe" for questions which are generally related to stripe but do not categorize for a specific sub category.

Comment: Please read: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work) and add the relevant information to the question here. Also note, that there is already a tag [tag:stripes]. It is impossible to create singular names when there is already a plural tag. Please also clearify why [tag:stripe-payments] and [tag:stripe-connect] are not what you want. The tag description indicates that this tag is for all questions about stripe.

Comment: Let's not.  "Stripe" is the company, [stripe-payments] and [stripe-connect] are the existing tags for their products.  We do not encourage users to ask questions about a company.

Comment: What sort of on-topic questions are currently not covered by the existing stripe-* tags?  If you can add some good examples (subjects or 1/2 sentence summaries should suffice), you may be able to turn this request around.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot say it any better than [Hans Passant did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391024/i-propose-to-add-stripe-tag-in-stackoverflow-for-the-general-questions-related/391087#comment738875_391024), so I'm going to quote him:

> Let's not.  "Stripe" is the company, [stripe-payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripe-payments) and [stripe-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripe-connect) are the existing tags for their products.  We do not encourage users to ask questions about a company.

Thus, for now, based on the information that is available to me, I'm declining this request.

If you wish for it to be reconsidered, then please review the guidelines in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work), and edit your question to include a more thorough justification, as [Dan Neely advised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391024/i-propose-to-add-stripe-tag-in-stackoverflow-for-the-general-questions-related#comment738880_391024).