# Add the [django-translated-fields] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I tried to add the tag [django-translated-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-translated-fields), but I didn't have enough reputation to add a new tag myself. This tag belongs to all the questions containing the string "django-translated-fields" on [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22django-translated-fields%22), 2 of them are mine. (one of the questions there is irrelevant to that search).

---

I asked a friend with privileges to create the tag for me (when I didn't have the privilege) and he did. But I checked and tags like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) have description, and I tried, but I couldn't edit the description of [django-translated-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-translated-fields). Does it also require privileges? I tried to submit a suggestion, but I can't see my suggestion, and I don't think it was accepted.

Comment: You need to address all the points in [how to create a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work) e.g. initial tag excerpt and wiki.

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried to submit a suggestion again.

Comment: Your edits are pending: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27016281 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27016282

Comment: I'm not thrilled by the excerpt or the wiki. You really need to explain in the excerpt and in the wiki which topics a question is about warrants adding the tag to it. The excerpts or wiki's are not advertisements for the topic. They are guidance. Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one

Comment: @rene I can't do better than what I did, but I will appreciate if the tag would contain a description, possibly written by other developers.