# Addition of an linux-security-module Tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-creation-process

The Linux Security Module landscape has increased rapidly since the kernel first utilised LSM hooks.

As this area matures, budding kernel hackers and code literate security engineers will be contributing to this area.

SE does not yet have an LSM tag, and I believe it is deserved. It takes a special collection of skills to be able to develop LSM's. Namely: c programming, knowledge of the Linux kernel and its data structures, and Security Access Control knowledge. TCP/IP networking and Unix sockets could also be added to this list.

As the LSM landscape will grow, and specific skills are necessary for this area, I believe a new tag will allow for easier aggregation, allowing posters and users to ask and find these questions more easily.

I believe my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59951679/5276801) would be a good candidate to add this tag to, however there are numerous questions on SO that pertain to LSM development

As @Paulie_D points out

> linux-security-module

would be the best name for the tag, to avoid confusion with any other acronym

Comment: There needs to be an existing question for the tag to be put on for it to be created.

Comment: Well my I be so bold to suggest my queston (there are plenty more) https://stackoverflow.com/q/59951679/5276801

Comment: You should add that to your question so it is easier to spot for someone who can create the tag.

Comment: You might want to check out [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work) and add the relevant info here.

Comment: Wouldn't [tag:linux-security-module] be a better tag than an acronym?

Answer (score 2):

A [linux-security-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-security-module) tag now exists, and has been added to your question.

I also created [lsm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lsm) as a synonym of that tag, since that acronym is not currently ambiguous in our tagging system. Having the synonym in place will prevent it from *becoming* ambiguous.

I also created the initial tag wiki excerpt for the [linux-security-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-security-module) tag, but I was not familiar with this concept until a few minutes ago, so it's unlikely that I wrote the best possible tag wiki excerpt. That could use attention from a subject matter expert.

As a side note, regarding [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951679/linux-security-module-development), I think that could do with a more descriptive title. Your current title is overly generic.