# Tag request [tt-net-sdk]

Tags: support, tags

I am a Product Manager at Trading Technologies, a global provider of high-performance professional trading software, infrastructure and data solutions. We offer several APIs / SDKs that are used by derivatives traders around the world. I would like to request that a new tag called [tt-net-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tt-net-sdk) be created and added to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566642/what-class-method-do-i-use-in-the-trading-technologies-net-sdk-to-indicate-that) question.

It is a specific reference to TT .NET SDK which provides developers with the ability to create applications that communicate with the TT platform. Specifically, applications can subscribe for prices, route orders (native and synthetic), and receive fills. We will be monitoring and answering questions marked with this tag. Thank you.

Comment: See this [FAQ for how to create new tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work). You'll need to have some existing, on topic questions that the tag would apply to for your request.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: I've read several posts related to product support and am already planning to follow accordingly.  The post above has been edited to include a link to a topic question.