# Do I need to ask a new question to create a tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

I'd like to create the `agda-stdlib` tag to add to another question, but the only way I can see is by asking a new question. Hence this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: It says "Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created." So as far as I understand I *do* have to create a new question to add a tag? Anyway, I should probably have posted this on meta, I'm sorry for the noise.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just edit your current one, you have the [required rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: It's a question by someone else (who doesn't have the required reputation).

Comment: also note: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: There also is tag [tag:standard-library]. Isn't combining it with [tag:agda]  an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

- Ask a question yourself
- Edit an existing question and add the tag

I highly recommend the latter, but that works better if you have at least 2.000 reputation and can make edits without them getting supervised, since only adding a single tag might be considered too minor to push an edit into the queue. If the question can benefit from more than just a tag edit, though, then go ahead.

If no questions exist yet that could benefit from the tag, I recommend waiting until they do. Others can create the tag too if they have sufficient reputation.

If you add a new tag, don't forget to propose an excerpt and wiki for it!

Comment: You don't need the rep when editing one of your own questions though, right?

Comment: Correct, well, just the 1.5K to be allowed to edit tags, so if you've already asked a question yourself you can edit that. If you don't have sufficient reputation to add tags, you can of course involve meta to get someone else to edit it in.