# Could someone add a new [datajoint] tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Could someone add a new datajoint tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376476/could-someone-add-a-new-datajoint-tag)

User @MadPhysicist mentioned that I had incorrectly posted on main instead of on meta. Apologies if so, I am new and still trying to learn how this all works. Would someone mind helping me fulfill this request? Below is the original request:

> [Maintainers at DataJoint](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python) are looking to move our support to StackOverflow but require someone with +1500 reputation to create a new [datajoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datajoint) tag for us. We would really appreciate if someone with this could create one for us? If so, there are already some questions related to [datajoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datajoint) that can be tagged as well. We can instruct our users to go ahead and use the new tag for questions going forward.
>
> The following are some of the existing questions related to DataJoint:
>
> - [Datajoint: Lock wait timeout exceeded errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986873/datajoint-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-errors)
> - [What is the correct ORDER BY syntax in DataJoint for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902970/what-is-the-correct-order-by-syntax-in-datajoint-for-python)
> - [Use a docker image to build a different docker image using a dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698713/use-a-docker-image-to-build-a-different-docker-image-using-a-dockerfile)
> - [ConnectionRefusedError: Unable to connect MySQL container while building docker image for a flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730264/connectionrefusederror-unable-to-connect-mysql-container-while-building-docker)
> - [python networkx import error: cannot import name release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105282/python-networkx-import-error-cannot-import-name-release)

[rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene), [RobertLongson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson), thanks for sharing these! I have reviewed the posts provided and below are the associated questions and responses related to the DataJoint open-source project of which I am a maintainer.

1. What is a good excerpt for the tag wiki?

- For general questions or debugging development errors as a result of using DataJoint, a framework for scientific workflow management. For assistance with debugging, please include: Client OS, DataJoint Client (Python|MATLAB), DataJoint Version, and Database Version (MySQL 5.7|MariaDB 10.5|etc).

2. Why we think the tag is appropriate?

- We have amassed a community of ~400 users and so far we have used Slack and GitHub Issues to respond to support request and general questions. However, as the community has grown, it has become challenging to filter through GitHub Issues for actual dev tasks vs general questions. Also, since Slack channel is not publicly exposed, users cannot rely on Googling to find answers and must explicitly search within the channel after joining. Therefore, we are looking to add a tag in StackOverflow so that we can begin to reccomend users to tag with the [datajoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datajoint) tag so that we can create an open community knowledge bank for general questions.

3. Are there existing questions where the tag would be appropriate?

- [Datajoint: Lock wait timeout exceeded errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986873/datajoint-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-errors)
- [What is the correct ORDER BY syntax in DataJoint for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902970/what-is-the-correct-order-by-syntax-in-datajoint-for-python)
- [Use a docker image to build a different docker image using a dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698713/use-a-docker-image-to-build-a-different-docker-image-using-a-dockerfile)
- [ConnectionRefusedError: Unable to connect MySQL container while building docker image for a flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730264/connectionrefusederror-unable-to-connect-mysql-container-while-building-docker)
- [python networkx import error: cannot import name release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105282/python-networkx-import-error-cannot-import-name-release)

4. For the questions above, is the tag on topic?

- For 1, question is quite specific to datajoint.
- For 2, this is a general datajoint question.
- For 3, this is specifically a user utilizing one of the datajoint open-source db images.
- For 4, this is a user utilizing the datajoint db image and attempting to install from source and have an issue where db is not yet accepting connections.
- For 5, is related to a known issue that datajoint had with one of our dependencies (networkx) until we patched it.

5. What is a good fitting name for the tag?

- datajoint

6. Where are there docs for datajoint?

- docs.datajoint.io

7. Are there any tags related to datajoint?

- Could not find any in https://stackoverflow.blog/?s=datajoint.

8. What is the community policy for certain feedback from users?

- How do i? (StackOverflow with datajoint tag)
- I got this error, why? (StackOverflow datajoint tag and OS/client/version details).
- Got this error and I'm sure it is a bug (file at https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/issues).
- I have an idea/request (file at https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/issues).
- Why do you? (Join our DataJoint Slack https://join.slack.com/t/datajoint/shared_invite/enQtMjkwNjQxMjI5MDk0LTQ3ZjFiZmNmNGVkYWFkYjgwYjdhNTBlZTBmMWEyZDc2NzZlYTBjOTNmYzYwOWRmOGFmN2MyYzU0OWQ0MWZiYTE).
- When will you? (see milestones in https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/milestones).
- Need help live debugging? (find us on DataJoint Slack https://join.slack.com/t/datajoint/shared_invite/enQtMjkwNjQxMjI5MDk0LTQ3ZjFiZmNmNGVkYWFkYjgwYjdhNTBlZTBmMWEyZDc2NzZlYTBjOTNmYzYwOWRmOGFmN2MyYzU0OWQ0MWZiYTE)

9. What is the plan for responsiveness?

- We will subscribe to any mention of the [datajoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datajoint) tag and periodically search for improperly tagged questions by adding/removing datajoint tag if applicable.

Addtional questions:

1. Should I formally submit an excerpt for the tag wiki somewhere?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: Those with the privilege should vote to delete the question on SO, or @Raphael you should delete it, since it's a question that belongs here on Meta, and you asked it here yourself.

Comment: @rene Thanks for providing those references. I have updated the question with more detail above.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes that helps and I believe my updates should provide a bit more clarity on this but please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @zcoop98 Thanks for sharing, I created the other question first but then realized that it would not allow me to create a meta post without it since I have less than 5 reputation. :sweat_smile: Am I safe to delete the one in main stackoverflow now?

Comment: @Raph Yep, no downsides there. It looks like it already got migrated, and closed, still no downside to deleting the now-duplicate meta question.

Comment: @zcoop98 Thanks! I have deleted the post I had originally created on main. Please let me know if there is anything else you'd like me to provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've gone ahead and created the tag [datajoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datajoint) for you. I tagged the suggested questions with it, except [ConnectionRefusedError: Unable to connect MySQL container while building docker image for a flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730264/connectionrefusederror-unable-to-connect-mysql-container-while-building-docker) as that question already has 5 tags and couldn't make the call which to remove as I am not a subject matter expert.

I've initially not added the tag excerpt because I'm not thrilled by the first advertorial blurb you provided. An excerpt and wiki need to explain when to use the tag on a  question. It doesn't need to explain what the concept is.  User that ask a question already know that. They need guidance how to ask a good question in the context of that tag. That is what needs to go in the excerpt and the wiki.

An maybe better example could be:

> For questions related to the software development aspects of the scientific workflow management framework for organizing, populating, computing, and querying data.

or the better suggestion you offered later in your question.

Please keep your tag clean of low quality posts and properly guide users when they ended up at wrong venue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ah that makes sense. I was not clear on the audience/context. Is there a place that I can edit this myself with a better description on intended use for the tag or should I reply it here for you?

Comment: @RaphaelGuzman feel free to edit your question here, we can put that into the tag information if it's appropriate.

Comment: @RaphaelGuzman you might go over https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one to have some more guidance and background on the goal of tag wiki and it is writing guidance. Either ping me or Robert if you updated your question.

Comment: @rene Thanks, the post helped. I have updated the tag wiki excerpt. Let me know if further adjustments are necessary.

Comment: @RaphaelGuzman okay, I've added that excerpt now: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datajoint/info