# Create [bimserver] tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

Can someone please create a tag [bimserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bimserver) for the [Opensource BIMserver](https://github.com/opensourcebim/bimserver)? The project has grown a community of users for about a decade, is built for software developers and there are already [36 questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bimserver) pertaining to it.

Most questions are also tagged [ifc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifc) and [bim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bim), which is correct, but not sufficient to distinguish BIMserver questions and answers from other IFC/BIM questions. IFC (Industry Foundation Classes) is a standard for data exchange in AEC (architecture, engineering, and construction) projects. BIM (Building Information Modelling) is the broader methodology of achieving an optimal exchange of information between construction project stakeholders across building lifecycle phases. There are various software systems, libraries and frameworks that support BIM and implement IFC, for example xBIM with a dedicated tag [xbim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xbim).

**Tag excerpt draft**

BIMserver is a platform to store and access building models in IFC format. Use this tag for questions on how to implement clients or plugins for BIMserver and details about its API.

**Tag wiki draft**

The [Opensource BIMserver](http://github.com/opensourcebim/bimserver) is a platform to store and retrieve building models in IFC format.

The IFC (Industry Foundation Classes) is an ISO standard for data exchange in the AEC (architecture, engineering, and construction) domain, standardized by [buildingSMART](https://www.buildingsmart.org/). The IFC are supposed to enable interoperability and facilitate exchange of information between the numerous actors (e.g. building-owners, architects, engineers, authorities) in AEC projects throughout all lifecycle phases of a construction or building, from early design to the point of demolition. This is commonly termed as BIM (Building Information Modelling).

The BIMserver API provides interfaces via JSON, SOAP and protobuf and extension points for serializers, deserializers, render engines and more. There are various plugins in separate repositories in the [OpensourceBIM organization](http://github.com/opensourcebim). Use this tag for questions on how to implement clients or plugins for BIMserver and details about its API.

BIMserver is written in Java and uses BerkeleyDB Java Edition as key-value store. More information on the BIMserver can be found in the [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/wiki), and bugs are to be posted in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/issues).

More information on the IFC and surrounding standards can be found at the [buildingSMART technical sites](http://technical.buildingsmart.org). Questions and answers related to the standard itself are more appropriate to be posted under the tag [ifc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifc) or in the [buildingSMART forums](https://forums.buildingsmart.org) under the various developer categories.

Comment: you'd need to address [all the points from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I have added drafts for the tag excerpt and wiki. I tried to follow the guidance given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337), but the drafts can certainly be improved. Are there any other points missing? I could go through the existing questions that mention BIMserver and filter out those which don't deserve the tag, e.g. because they apply to any jar or war or because they ask about the usage of existing clients or plugins, not the development of new or improved ones.

Comment: Perhaps a little less weasel wordy? *"...seamless flow of information across project stakeholders..."* [It should also make sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turboencabulator). Flow is usually *through* something and in this context usually not through carbon-based lifeforms. Stakeholders (from [Scrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development))?) have interests and roles, not something flowing through or across them.

Comment: No, I am not referring to Scrum. In this case, a project has the aim to create a building or construction artifact (not a a software application) and stakeholders are the building-owner, professionals from the various architectural and engineering domains, authorities to approve the construction plans etc. They exchange information from the first design ideas to the planning and execution and even further through the construction's operation phase and finally its teardown.

Comment: It's very close to marketing speak. Tag excerpts should tell the user why they'd want to use the tag, not what the word means. Tag wikis should talk about why you'd use the tag over other similar tags, and include FAQs and links to official documentation sources where available.

Comment: I tried to follow the advice [for tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/) and thought it would be appropriate to include the explanation of the acronyms IFC and BIM as "general background information on the subject". But I don't mind to remove the whole paragraph. Indeed it is probably safe to assume people know the meaning of these when they consider to use the tag, because there is no competing widespread use of the acronyms as far as I know.