# Remove tag [keyless-entity]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I spotted a relatively new tag [keyless-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyless-entity). It's got 5 questions in the past 6 months. I think it should be removed but I'd like to discuss that first.

[Keyless Entity Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) is a feature in Entity Framework, Microsoft's flagship OR-mapper, one of many, obviously. Does one specific feature justify a new tag? Keyless Entities isn't a concept that's hard to grasp, I haven't seen many questions about it and don't expect lots of them to come either. Also, I don't think it's a common phrase in other technology stacks. (Theoretically, it's even a contradiction in terms).

Excerpt from [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

Excerpt from [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/861716):

> if you think there is a **clear need** for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself. Uncommon topics are perfectly valid for a tag, as long as they're still clearly defined. Try to submit at least an excerpt for the tag wiki so others can see its intended use.

In short: I don't see a *clear need* here and I propose removal now it can still be done without causing much noise. I don't think it requires the tag burnination procedure.

---

As Rene suggested, scoring against the 4 criteria of tag burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

In the context of Entity Framework: yes

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

This is where I'm not sure. Yes, it is about an EF feature, but it's enough to mention it in the text and, as said, we're not going to add tags for all possible features.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I don't think there are any other contexts.

Comment: Maybe also score the tag against [the 4 criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/158100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think removal of that tag is okay here, despite it not causing any harm yet.

One aspect I also like to consider for tags is how experts would use that tag to filter their potential questions to answer. They either watch the tag or ignore the tag. This becomes beneficial in tags with reasonable traffic and some major feature chunks. Think [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

I can't imagine that keyless-entity is a major feature that makes followers of the entity framework get acute nausea when they stumble on such question by accident. It doesn't need a high level of specific knowledge to handle these questions either.

The tag has no additional value to find or categorize these questions within its main tag. Given it is just 5 questions you're free to remove them over the next day or so. Once removed from all questions the tag will be obliterated in the 03:00 UTC tag clean-up batch job.

Additionally: the [burnination guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) states:

> If you have authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help.

I'm a trusted community member, with a gold badge in C#. You've done your due diligence. Burn the tag.

Comment: I see no reason whatsoever to remove this tag. If you don't want to watch on it, then you don't have to. @GertArnold I see no way in which this tag is creating harm. It meets *none* of the criteria for burnination/removal.

Comment: @CodyGray Isn't a tag being not necessary enough for removing it? I don't necessarily disagree with you but I like to understand when creating a new tag is justified. Despite the help and faq links I shared I'm still not sure. The phrase **clear need** isn't really conclusive.

Comment: No, lack of necessity is not cause for removal. The bar is high for creating a new tag, just as it's high for removing an existing tag. There has to be a clear and compelling reason for making modifications to the tagging system.

Comment: @CodyGray OK, I'll leave it until we agree there's a compelling reason. Maybe it's my developer background. In code, redundancy isn't as harmless as in tags.

Comment: @GertArnold if "clear need" isn't conclusive, maybe you should read the thing written later on "you should avoid creating new tags if possible" or "you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that **your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about** before on this site"

Comment: @Braiam As I did (I quoted it). The feature is relatively new and "nobody else has asked about before" isn't always followed. New tags may get added in retrospect.

Comment: OK, completed now (thanks @Machavity). That's it then.

Comment: One possible use would be if the MS Devs behind Keyless Entity Types are following the tag to provide support for it.