# Add tag [minecraft-fabric]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I recently found out that there is no minecraft-fabric tag. Fabric is a

> [lightweight, experimental modding toolchain for Minecraft](https://fabricmc.net/)

similar to Forge. I've yet to find reliable statistics online, but according to many mod developers the minecraft modding community is more or less equally split between using these two, with fabric being more popular in new minecraft releases.

Both minecraft and minecraft-forge has a tag, so it would make sense to create a tag for Fabric as well, and I created this post to discuss whether the majority would approve of it.

From [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong
> case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked
> about before on this site.

I couldn't find any other tags referring to the fabric modding api, so I'm pretty sure it is a new tag.

From [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)
:

> Topics to be addressed by you in the Meta question are, but not
> limited to:
>
> - Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate
> - Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow
> - Explain how the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions
> - Provide an initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag, see here.
> - Propose a good fitting name for the tag as they are always lowercase, don't take spaces and have a maximum length of 35
>   characters.

1. I found numerous questions in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bminecraft%5D+fabric (questions tagged with minecraft and contain 'fabric') and there is probably many other ones (but it is difficult to search).
2. The [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag has always been debated, but the [minecraft-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge) and other (like [bukkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bukkit)) tags are generally accepted. Questions about fabric would be roughly as on-topic as the forge or bukkit ones.
3. There is currently no (efficient) way to search for questions related to Fabric. It is a very distinct category and can be used to identify the topic of the questions.
4. I don't have a tag wiki yet, and I don't think I could write it with high quality by myself. I hope there is someone more skilled and knowledgeable in the community.
5. My suggestion is [minecraft-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-fabric). This would help avoid confusion with other tags such as [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) (a python library) and [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric), and follows the format of [minecraft-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge).

Comment: I made the tag -- needs to be added to the relevant questions, though.

Comment: Even if you don't think you can write a high quality tag wiki for it, if you can provide a brief description you feel would be appropriate for the tag, that would be helpful for it. As @Zoe has now created it, you can even submit an edit request on it: [tag:minecraft-fabric]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag has been created by Zoe. Since I received no objections, I consider this topic closed.