# How to handle a question regarding a third party control in another language?

Tags: discussion

Here's the question:

[While creating HMSegment got error: [UIView setSelectionIndicatorLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672399/while-creating-hmsegment-got-error-uiview-setselectionindicatorlocation-unr)

It's only tagged as Swift, but the error is obviously Objective-C. More, it's about a third party project from GitHub:

https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

I wanted to simply add a tag for this control, but none exists. (Maybe I can create one with my level of points here, but didn't.) I wanted - and did in a comment - direct the OP to communicate with the creator.

I then voted to close this. Was that wrong? If not, what should the reason be? If this was wrong, I'll remove my vote.

**Edit:**

- While the error is Objective-C, should I have simply tagged it as such?

Comment: There is no need to create a tag for every control out there; only create tags for subjects that are popular enough to need distinct sorting out. See [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you. So I guess my question ends up being was my close vote correct? (It *is* about code, but not necessarily about the same coding language as the OP is working in.)

Comment: I didn't really look at the question until now. I don't see any reason why that post should be closed though. Questions on how to use 3rd party libraries and controls correctly is certainly on topic for SO. I'm rather green around the ears when it comes to iOS development, so I can't comment on the use of tags there.

Comment: I'll leave my comment (directing them to contact the creator) and remove my vote. Again, thanks!

Comment: For tagging you might ask yourself: "will the experts that follow this tag be happy to see that question and are they able to answer it". Adding the C++ tag to a C question is doing a lot of users a disfavor. Not sure how swift and objective-c folks go along.