# Create the [got-npm] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-request

I'd like to request a tag for the HTTP request library [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got). The [got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/got) tag is already in use, so I'd propose [got-npm] but happy to hear better suggestions. I don't have enough reputation to create this myself.

It's a reasonably popular library, and given that [request](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) is no longer maintained, likely to become more so. And unfortunately, it also has a name that makes it near impossible to actually search for it directly, which makes it hard to find (and hard to answer) questions for it.  It's possible to find some using the node.js and https tags, but both are very popular so specific questions about got are swamped in the rest.

There already are tags for similar libraries: [axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axios), [superagent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superagent), and [node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-fetch).

### tag wiki excerpt

> Got is a lightweight HTTP request library for Node.js, written in Typescript.
>
> HTTP request library for Node.js, available on [Github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got).

### Examples of questions that should have such a tag

[NodeJS - HTTPS POST request not working with Got client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559430/nodejs-https-post-request-not-working-with-got-client)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866341/https-request-with-got

[How to use http request headers in Got?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357332/how-to-use-http-request-headers-in-got)

Comment: The library name is "got", it's distributed through "npm". I don't think the name "got-npm" makes any sense - it's not related to NPM. We don't name libraries based on how they are distributed. Or we'd have maven-apache-commons or cdn-jquery which doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Something like `node-got`?

Comment: Hmm, looking at the [[tag:got]] - seems like some questions are already using the tag but aren't at all related to "global offset table". Instead they actually mean the got library

Comment: @yivi dunno. The node-fetch library is literally called "node-fetch" - both words. While "got" is called just "got" which is honestly a terrible name all around. It's funny for 5 seconds until you try to look up anything. Same problem that the Prototype library had. At any rate, it's a library *for* Node.js but I'm not sure calling it "node-got" is accurate. It could work on Deno, I imagine. And maybe in the future it goes to the browser. Which...node-fetch does, actually. Let's say, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: we have a [fair share](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=library&starts=0) of `*-library`-postfixed tags, maybe [got-library] will suffice?

Comment: I just want to commend and thank you for making a high quality tag request post that includes [all the needed pieces](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work/252945#who-can-create-a-tag). It's really helpful!

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to me to use [got] for the library and [global-offset-table] for the acronym.  The current tag has questions related to both but it’s a small enough number that the questions can be manually sorted.  I’m happy to help with that or do it myself if we can get a consensus that this is okay.

Comment: @LindaPaiste to be honest, I'm with you there. [At a glance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+or+%5Bnode.js%5D+and+%5Bgot%5D) it seems there are 15 questions tagged [[tag:got]] that are about the library out of the 55 total questions in the tag. I've not looked through the list thoroughly but there are probably 40-ish questions to retag. Or maybe just 15 if a mod does some switcheroo with the tags. E.g., got library questions to got-temp the rest of got questions to global-offset-table then got-temp to got. Unless there is some tools mods have that makes it even easier.

Comment: It sounds like there's some support for @LindaPaiste's suggestion - so should I edit the title to reflect that this is now intended to rename/migrate a current tag rather than just creating a new tag?

Comment: Stumbled across an existing tag: [gotjs] already exists. There seem to be other JS libraries suffixed with js, so it's logical. So it may make more sense to stick with this existing tag, and retag the JS questions under the [got] tag to [gotjs] rather than creating a new [global-offset-tag] and migrating. If there's support for this then I guess I should close this question?