# This tag [got] me confused

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/got) is being used for at least two purposes:

- Global Offset Table (the only meaning specified in the tag wiki)
- [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#readme), an HTTP library for Node.js

Not counting the case of the word "got" in an error message, clearly a misuse.

What can be done to disambiguate this tag?

Comment: I've made [node.js-got] in keeping with existing nomenclature. We can use that to disambiguate, then rename [got] to [global-offset-table]

Comment: [got] got GOTO 0 confused? goot!

Comment: At the moment, there are just 64 questions with the [tag:got] tag.  Four of the top 30 answerers have answered multiple questions; three of the top 30 askers have asked multiple questions.  Only one question has been asked in the last 30 days.  Almost half the questions have no (upvoted) answer.

Comment: Related: [Tag request \[got-npm\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406379)

Comment: It's not being used for Game of Thrones questions? I'm surprised.

Comment: @yivi make it a synonym for [a-song-of-ice-and-fire]

Comment: @yivi surprised that nobody saw it as a green flag for writing posts in old gothic language or something like that

Comment: [got]? Isn't that where Sean Bean gets beheaded in season 1?

Comment: I just love all the puns in the questions (and comments) related to tags!!

Comment: ?    '  '?

Comment: @VLAZ We already have [tag:gotjs] for the Node.js HTTP library. The [tag:got] shouldn't be used for the library

Comment: @cocomac The problem is that nobody can find that tag (part of that is the poor way the tagging system works in general because it takes the top 6 populated tags matching whatever you typed in). The project is also named got (I assume it's a riff on GET, which is how HTTP generally requests pages), not gotjs. We'll need to merge that tag as well

Comment: We've [tag:Got] [tag:.a] [tag:question2answer] [tag:overthere]: [tag:can] [tag:tags] [tag:write] [tag:.a] [tag:sentence]?

Comment: There is gotjs tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gotjs

Comment: @SylvesterKruin _le sigh_ that's the thing I've telling people about tags: they are not supposed to be able to build sentences with them, they aren't keywords!

Comment: @LeosLiterak Just in case you didn't know, you can use the `[tag:tagname]` syntax to type a tag name, so you don't have to type or copy the whole link.

Comment: @Machavity: Any reason your top comment isn't an answer? It seems like the best here. I shied away from it because I though global-offset-table was too long but clearly it isn't.

Comment: One option would be to rename it to [global-offset-table], but part of the issue here is that some people running into linker errors don't know what GOT stands for.  That's not necessarily a showstopper, but something to consider.  I can't think of a good name that includes "got" but also includes disambiguation for the Unix dynamic-linking tag.  [dynamic-linker-got] seems terrible, like not how anyone wants to think of the GOT.  [got-dynamic-linking] or [got-linking] are just as bad, with the added "bonus" of sounding like a reference to the Got Milk ad campaign.

Comment: @Smile I do too. Did my comment make you smile, @Smile? :)