# Should incomplete tag requests be closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, meta, tag-creation-process

I took a look at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406785/can-a-tag-for-pymoo-be-created) and discovered that it has been closed as a duplicate. I believe this is **incorrect**, and that the post should be closed as needing details and clarity.

Let's see the flags' descriptions:

- a duplicate: This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
- Needs details or clarity: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

I think it's pretty clear that it makes no sense for the question to be closed as a duplicate. For this question, the OP is requesting that a tag be made for Pymoo. It does not already have an answer; the "duplicate" of simply talks about what a tag request should contain, not whether a tag should be made for Pymoo. The question does, however, not contain all the **details** that a tag request should have.

Now, Alexei Levenkov disagreed with me and said this:

> In general I'm in favor of not starting re-close for a different reason and I think duplicate of FAQ actually more beneficial to OP than downvotes/"not enough info" close votes...

It may be somewhat beneficial, but it simply doesn't match the specifications of being a duplicate. I believe it would be far better and clearer to close the question for needing details or clarity and then leaving a comment saying,

> Please improve your question according to [these specifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).

Plus, I think starting a re-close is perfectly justified so as not to confuse future readers who may legitimately want a Pymoo tag, and then check the duplicate and find nothing about it.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I feel closing against the FAQ is fine in this specific case. The closure, however, would ideally have been accompanied by a comment outlining what was missing in the request, along the lines of what Alexei Levenkov posted a few hours later.

Comment: I think this is a side effect of how closure is implemented. Gold badge holders can instantly close as a duplicate. That means that the OP can get imperfect feedback that the question doesn't contain the information we need much earlier than if they had a comment on a question that was left open for a much longer period as 4 other people would then need to weigh in to get it closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, questions that are not answerable and/or actionable should be closed, as quickly as possible.

If we pick a non-dupe reason we have either re-iterate all the awesome guidance from the FAQ or link to it from the comments. Closing as a duplicate is the shortest path to excellent guidance. If I or one of my fellow gold badge holders vote it is insta closed as well.

Remember that on Meta I can even wield my hammer to duplicates that have no answer at all. I happily abuse that privilege.

Once closed, the OP has all the time to read the stuff they should have done before asking, gather the info they are missing, decide on the improvements to be made and submit edits to get the question into an answerable / actionable state. After that edit there is no lack of users that happily sit in the review queue and click re-open.

I don't see why a comment is any better than a close notice. If they start editing and still appear to be misguided it is early enough to offer more tailored guidance to the OP.

As for the specific case: If that gets re-opened (it currently has 4 re-open votes) I'll dupe hammer it again (which I just did). That tag request is not actionable in its current state. It should be edited first, by the OP, foremost the plagiarized wiki proposal should be removed.  For everyone's convenience / laziness I also added an extra comment to point out what else needs to be edited in on top of what was already suggested in other comments.

Comment: TL;DR - Edit, then vote to reopen.