# Is it possible to create Public Teams?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I want to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A forum for our product.
It has nothing to do with coding, so it does not fit the default Stack Overflow community.

I created a team, but the team is private. I want customers to be able to join and ask questions, as advertised here:
https://stackoverflow.com/teams/use-cases/customer-support

Is there no way to have a "public" team, where anyone can register, but without getting it mixed up with the public Stack Overflow?

How are customers supposed to send tickets if they have no access? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you can't .

Comment: @Zoe but why does it advertise "Stack Overflow for support" then?
https://stackoverflow.com/teams/use-cases/customer-support

How can customers send support tickets if they have no access? Surely it doesn't expect me to manually create users for everyone? Especially free-tier users.

Comment: That page is supposed to mean that it enables the support team to have access to questions and answers, not for end-users in need of support to be able to search questions and answers. SO teams has never been intended for that. There's no mode where you open the team for public reading, so yes, if you wanna use it for that, you need to manually make accounts, or otherwise hack around to make a system to automate that process. That said, I believe this is going to be status-declined because it goes outside the scope of what teams was for in the first place.

Comment: If you need public questions, you make a tag on main. If your use is off-topic, try on another site.

Comment: Re: the support case again, read further on the page. It says "**Empower the support team to find information and answers in the moment.** Capture common questions and document unique cases for ongoing collaboration" - which, again, means it's not meant for customers. As far as ticketing systems go, SO for teams is awful anyway. You're better off using a system meant for support tickets, and not make a hackish solution using Q&A software

Comment: `...Stack Overflow as a Q&A forum for our product...`? Q/A doesn't work well for discussion forums

Comment: thanks for clarifying! Too bad it can't be used for company forums, I would def pay for that.

Comment: Well, if you're willing to pay, and really want it open to the public,and thus, potentially high volume, SE does have enterprise level Q&A offerings. I have no idea what SE's pricing structure is, requirements, etc., or even if it's something that would fit. However, it probably wouldn't hurt to [contact them](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise/get-started) to get more information.

Comment: *"Too bad it can't be used for company forums"* there's your first mistake; [so] and the other sites in the community aren't forums.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can't create a public team. Teams does not support public sign-up, a public read-only mode, or otherwise letting any random person for any random reason join a team for a random period of time. It's fundamentally meant to be a private source of info.

Since you brought it up in the comments, the customer support use case is meant to empower the *support team*, not customers, which it also says on the site:

> Empower the support team to find information and answers in the moment. Capture common questions and document unique cases for ongoing collaboration

The ticketing system is then meant to be external, and depends on the support form. Some companies might use phone support, some might use a digital ticketing system, or something completely different. What may or may not be used is beside the point, but the support ticket system isn't meant to be teams.

If you want a public Q&A, that's what *[the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)* public Q&A is meant for. If your use case is off-topic for Stack Overflow, try elsewhere in the network. If it's completely off-topic to the entire network, then you need to figure out another solution. Tag creation has a low bar, and if you don't have the privilege, [you can request it on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).

And if you still insist on using teams, you can manually make your own hackish system to make it "public", in the meaning that you enable arbitrary sign-ups, but that assumes it's not a [ToS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TOS#Noun) violation (haven't checked), and that you're willing to pay for users when you inevitably exceed 50 users. And, again, teams wasn't made with this use case in mind in the first place. Q&As aren't ticket systems, but it really depends on what your actual use case is. There are a few use cases where the answer simply is that neither teams, nor SO or the network is fit for that particular use.

#### TL;DR:

> How are customers supposed to send tickets if they have no access? Am I missing something?

They're not. They're supposed to send tickets to a different system (whatever your organization uses), and your support staff can then use Teams to handle the ticket by finding information on how to handle it. SO for teams isn't a ticket system.

Comment: thanks for the very in depth answer, this answered all my questions.
I moved to https://www.talkyard.io/ and will be using it as self-hosted solution.

Answer (score 2):

We have a number of customers who are using Stack Overflow for Teams for a support solution for their customers.

I noticed that you initially said that you couldn’t pay for each user. To use the product for support, you would need to pay for the Business or Enterprise tier because it requires a special set up. Additionally our Customer Success team helps get this up and running and provides ongoing guidance and support.

If you’d like to hear more about how companies are using it as a customer support solution, we have a couple of pieces that you can read ([here](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/teams/no-code-apps-distrupting-analog-services)) or watch ([here](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/teams/centarro-uses-stack-overflow-for-teams-for-effective-customer-support)) to see more about how other companies are doing it.