# Create the [image-js] tag (can't add it as it is similar to the [imagej] tag)

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

Clearly, [image-js](https://github.com/image-js/image-js) is different from [imagej](https://github.com/imagej) and should have its own new tag — [image-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-js).

Question example:

[How do you normalize an image (histogram stretching) using image-js and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595948/how-do-you-normalize-an-image-using-image-js-and-javascript/69623360#69623360)

Comment: Which questions should have this new tag? Please [edit] your proposal with examples.

Comment: Why do we need an image-js tag? Please include examples of questions on which this tag could be used, and be sure you've read [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)

Comment: Are there questions about these that aren't covered by other tags?

Comment: its very hard to search for  "image-js" because there is a lot of "image js" unrelated results, most people tag it as `image` which is not correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549485/how-do-you-upscale-a-512x512-to-2017x2017-heightmap-array-of-pixels-of-a-png-ima

Comment: @Braiam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69329523/node-js-canvas-loadimage-and-image-load-throw-out-of-memory-when-loading-pngs

Comment: @Jabbar that last one is not about image-js, it's about node-canvas. It's just that one of the modules there is called image.js, but once again no relation with image-js.